# How to detect Passenger Seatbelt Indicator using OBD2

Tags: obd-ii, elm-327

I have trouble code information as below for **B00D1 OBD Trouble Code**
which use to detect **Passenger Seatbelt Indication**.

I am referring below links to get trouble code information:

http://www.dtcsearch.com/B00D1/Generic/

http://www.obd-codes.com/b00d1

http://upkeep.us/OBDII/OBD2/Honda/piart.php?art=2607

Can any one help to how to detect **Passenger Seatbelt Indication** using obd2. Any thoughts on how to achieve this and is it possible?

Comment: Since this is vehicle specific (and really for any question) you should list the make and model of your vehicle.

Comment: Seat belt indicators aren't part of the OBD standard. You'd have to reverse engineer the proprietary protocol the dealer's diagnostic tool uses to talk to the car's computers and go from there, as I'm sure this info would be available if you ask nicely using the right protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OBD II only guarantees communication and specific PID availability with the engine computer. For effect I repeat, ONLY the engine computer.

The passenger seat belt indicator would be either part of the body control system or the restraint/airbag system. These are manufacturer specific and will change depending on the make, model and year of the car.

There is no single PID or code that covers every car.

Comment: But if car have seat belt indicator then we can able to get data regarding seat belt. I am referring [Mode 3 (no PID required) PID for body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#Mode_3_.28no_PID_required.29)

Comment: @pRaNaY Seat belt status won't be available as a code, only a PID. Also this will be different of EVERY make model and year. There will be no consistency at all because this is a manufacturer specific feature.

Comment: @pRaNaY as vini_i mentioned, this is VERY vehicle specific. Some cars have a seat belt indicator, not all of those cars have an available PID for it. Your question is also very unclear, what are you trying to accomplish?